# How do I run curl command from within a Kubernetes pod

Tags: docker, containers, kubernetes

I have the following questions:

1. I am logged into a Kubernetes pod using the following command:

   ```
    ./cluster/kubectl.sh exec my-nginx-0onux -c my-nginx -it bash
   ```

   The 'ip addr show' command shows its assigned the ip of the pod. Since pod is a logical concept, I am assuming I am logged into a docker container and not a pod, In which case, the pod IP is same as docker container IP. Is that understanding correct?
2. from a Kubernetes node, I do `sudo docker ps` and then do the following:-

   ```
    sudo docker exec  71721cb14283 -it '/bin/bash'
   ```

   This doesn't work. Does someone know what I am doing wrong?
3. I want to access the nginx service I created, from within the pod using curl. How can I install curl within this pod or container to access the service from inside. I want to do this to understand the network connectivity.

Answer (score 95):

Here is how you get a curl command line within a kubernetes network to test and explore your internal REST endpoints.

To get a prompt of a busybox running inside the network, execute the following command. (A tip is to use one unique container per developer.)

```bash
kubectl run curl-<YOUR NAME> --image=radial/busyboxplus:curl -i --tty --rm
```

You may omit the --rm and keep the instance running for later re-usage. To reuse it later, type:

```bash
kubectl attach <POD ID> -c curl-<YOUR NAME> -i -t
```

Using the command `kubectl get pods` you can see all running POD's. The `<POD ID>` is something similar to `curl-yourname-944940652-fvj28`.

**EDIT:** Note that you need to login to google cloud from your terminal (once) before you can do this! Here is an example, make sure to put in your zone, cluster and project:

```bash
gcloud container clusters get-credentials example-cluster --zone europe-west1-c --project example-148812
```

Comment: Just curious, what is the reason you suggested to name the pod `curl` while the OP just want to run `ip` in a shell? As a result, we see `curl` everywhere while the `curl` command is not used at all. It is actually the same pattern I saw in [Connecting Applications with Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/connect-applications-service/#dns)

Answer (score 26):

The idea of **Kubernetes** is that *pods* are assigned on a *host* but there is nothing sure or permanent, so you should NOT try to look up the IP of a container or pod from your container, but rather use what Kubernetes calls a **Service**.

A Kubernetes **Service** is a path to a pod with a defined set of selectors, through the `kube-proxy`, which will load balance the request to all pods with the given selectors.

In short:

create a **Pod** with a *label* called 'name' for example. let's say `name=mypod`
create a **Service** with the *selector* `name=mypod` that you call `myService` for example, to which you assign the port `9000` for example.

then you can curl from a pod to the pods served by this Service using 
`curl http://myService:9000`

This is assuming you have the DNS pod running of course.
If you ask for a *LoadBalancer* type of *Service* when creating it, and run on AWS or GKE, this service will also be available from outside your cluster. For internal only service, just set the flag `clusterIP: None` and it will not be load balanced on the outside.

see reference here:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/

Answer (score 17):

There's an official curl team image these days:

https://hub.docker.com/r/curlimages/curl

Run it with:

> kubectl run -it --rm --image=curlimages/curl curly -- sh

Answer (score 12):

1. Kubernetes uses the [IP-per-pod](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/4ca66d2aefa20c27b670b2fa890052daadc05294/docs/admin/networking.md#kubernetes-model) model. All containers in the same pod share the same IP address as if they are running on the same host.
2. The command should follow `docker exec [OPTIONS] CONTAINER COMMAND [ARG...]`. In your case, `sudo docker exec -it 71721cb14283 '/bin/bash'` should work. If not, you should provide the output of your command.
3. It depends on what image you use. There is nothing special about installing a software in a container. For nginx, try `apt-get update && apt-get install curl`

Comment: thanks Yu, i think it makes sense now. So my understanding is right that i am logged into a container and all containers within the same pod would show the same ip. docker exec worked with your example. Sorry i didnt pay enough attention. I wasnt still able to install curl on a nginx pod in gce though but was able to get around it with another container which i installed with curl to test connectivity from container to service.