# why my kubernetes service doesn't target pods

Tags: kubernetes

I have a kubernetes service, and I wanna it to target pods.

This is how I define my service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: my-service
spec:
    selector:
            app: myapp
    ports:
        - port: 77
          targetPort: 80
          nodePort: 32766
    type: NodePort
```

and this is how I define my deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: my-deployment
spec:
    replicas: 5
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: myapp
    template:
        metadata:
            name: my-pod
            labels:
                app: myapp
        spec:
            containers:
                - name: httd
                  image: httpd
                  imagePullPolicy: Always
                  ports:
                      - containerPort: 80
```

Basically what I did is linking port 80 in the pod to port 77 in the service to port 32766 in the node.

I already know that my container is running on port 80 because If I do this:

```
docker run -p 8989:80 httpd
```

and ask for localhost:8989 I can see the page.

If I do kubetctl get services I get:

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        46h
my-service   NodePort    10.100.157.161   <none>        77:32766/TCP   20m
```

I tried calling:

```
10.100.157.161:32766
10.100.157.161:77
```

But both give connection error.

What did I miss?

Comment: How did you call those addresses? From within the cluster, or from outside the cluster?

Comment: @BurakSerdar I am on my machine, so I am calling them from my browser

Comment: The cluster IP network is probably not accesible to you. Is the k8s cluster on your machine as well? If so, try localhost:32766. Otherwise, try host:32766 where host is one of the k8s worker hosts.

Comment: @BurakSerdar yes I am running minikube on my local machine. and I tried localhost:32766 but also connection error.

Comment: Is it running on a virtual machine? If so, try the address of the virtual machine

Comment: @BurakSerdar No it is not. I runs on my machine (physical machine) using minikube cluster

Comment: Is your pod running?

Comment: @BurakSerdar yes as usual

Comment: @BurakSerdar what I suspect is that the service actually links the port correctly, but maybe the port doesn't expose the port of the container correctly. What do you think?

Comment: To test that, exec into your running pod, and try hitting those addresses from within the cluster

Comment: @BurakSerdar I tried to do it using `k exec -it my-deployment-75ddcfb857-2prn8  -c httd bash` but neither ping not curl exists in the container

Comment: @BurakSerdar could you try my files on your machine? and see if you can access the service?

Comment: Try running curl with busybox

Comment: @BurakSerdar sorry what is busybox?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601650/how-do-i-run-curl-command-from-within-a-kubernetes-pod

Comment: @JackThomson - I'd suggest to find out the IP address of the host and try with that (e.g. `1.2.3.4:32766`) instead of `localhost:32766`. In any case, to see if the Service properly targets any pods, run `kubectl -n <namespace> describe svc <service-name>` and look for at least one `Endpoints`.

Comment: @gears I can see the five endpoints in m services description as `172.17.0.4:80,172.17.0.5:80,172.17.0.6:80 + 2 more...` and I did try using my internal ip address http://192.168.1.32/ but also nothing works :( :(

Comment: @BurakSerdar yea I tried the link you suggested, it doesn't see that anything is being called correctly as shown in this screenshot https://ibb.co/wrNWVDh

Comment: @JackThomson I think you do not have a working network for your cluster.

Comment: @BurakSerdar I found it! `minikube service my-service` I don't know what this statement does, but it works!!!

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys. Problems solved!

Answer (score 1):

Use the below YAMLs. It works

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myapp
  name: my-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: httpd
        name: httpd
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: myapp
  ports:
  - port: 77
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 32766
  type: NodePort
```

```
master $ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        15m
my-service   NodePort    10.110.219.232   <none>        77:32766/TCP   12s
master $
master $
master $ curl 10.110.219.232:77
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
master $
master $
master $ curl $(hostname -i):32766
<html><body><h1>It works!</h1></body></html>
master $
```