# Eclipse Hono 1.1.1 Installed using Kubernetes - Probelm in Creating a Tenant

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, eclipse-hono

I have installed Eclipse Hono 1.1.1 Kubernetic cluster using Helm as per the below instructions.

https://hub.helm.sh/charts/eclipse-iot/hono

Initially I tried to create a tenant using the below command

```
curl -X POST "http://servername:28080/v1/tenants/DEFAULT_TENANT123" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

But then I got the Resource not found error.

And then as per the instructions in the [How do i run curl command from within a Kubernetes pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34601650/how-do-i-run-curl-command-from-within-a-kubernetes-pod)

```
curl -X POST "http://ServiceName:Serviceport/v1/tenants/DEFAULT_TENANT123" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Again it dint work..!!!

I tried the following command to enter into the device registry pod

```
 kubectl exec -it honohelmdeploy-service-device-registry-0 -- sh
```

And inside the device registry pod, I tried to run the above command and still it dint work.

I am not sure what should be the Host and Port while using the below command

```
curl -X POST "http://HOST:PORT/v1/tenants/DEFAULT_TENANT123" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

I tried using device registry service name/ device registry pod name as hosts.
I tried using device registry ports
I tried using my server name / localhost as hosts..
I tried using 28080 as ports..

But I was not able to create a Tenant. Please assist.

Edited with the screeshot for kubectl get svc command
[image]

Comment: What kind of Kubernetes cluster did you install Hono to? Minikube? Azure AKS?

Comment: I am using Minikube

Comment: I used the following commands

To create a Repo - helm repo add eclipse-iot https://www.eclipse.org/packages/charts/ 

To install the chart - helm install eclipse-iot/hono --version 1.3.0

Comment: What `Services` do you have in your cluster ? What does `kubectl get svc` say ? What did you replace `ServiceName:Serviceport` with ?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I have edited the question with kubectl get svc command. I tried service name as honohelmdeploy-service-device-registry-ext and honohelmdeploy-service-device-registry but both dint work.
I tried ports 28080, 31080 and they dint work. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it seems like you have installed Hono to minikube without any loadbalancer running. You can see this from the *EXTERNAL-IP* column which contains `<pending>` for all of Hono's (externally visible) service endpoints.

You need to start `minikube tunnel` in order for these endpoints to be exposed via a loadbalancer as described in the chart's README. You should be able to run the `minikube tunnel` command either before or after having installed Hono to the cluster. Once the loadbalancer is running, the *EXTERNAL-IP* addresses should be bound and you should be able to access the service endpoints.